# Three.js custom geometry problems with rotation

Tags: javascript, three.js, webgl

I have just started working with Javascript and specifically three.js. I have a custom Geometry that i have used to create a triangular prism. It has produced the correct shape but when it is rotated some of the faces don't look right. The other built in geometries (CubeGeometry, CylinderGeometry...) work just fine. Does it have to do with my custom Geometry or does it have something to do with lighting? Or the Mesh or Material?

Here is the fiddle for an example of what is happening: [3D Shapes Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/JLKCU/1/)

Here is the relevant code:

```
function getTriPrismGeometry(){
    var geometry = new THREE.Geometry()

    geometry.vertices.push( new THREE.Vertex(new THREE.Vector3( -100,  100, 0 )) );
    geometry.vertices.push( new THREE.Vertex(new THREE.Vector3( -100, -100, 0 ) ));
    geometry.vertices.push( new THREE.Vertex(new THREE.Vector3(  100, -100, 0 )) );
    geometry.vertices.push( new THREE.Vertex(new THREE.Vector3( -100,  100, -100 )) );
    geometry.vertices.push( new THREE.Vertex(new THREE.Vector3( -100, -100, -100 ) ));
    geometry.vertices.push( new THREE.Vertex(new THREE.Vector3(  100, -100, -100 )) );

    geometry.faces.push( new THREE.Face3(0,1,2 ) );
    geometry.faces.push( new THREE.Face3(3,4,0 ) );
    geometry.faces.push( new THREE.Face3( 0, 1, 4 ) );
    geometry.faces.push( new THREE.Face3( 1, 4, 5 ) );
    geometry.faces.push( new THREE.Face3( 1, 2,5) );
    geometry.faces.push( new THREE.Face3( 2, 0, 3 ) );
    geometry.faces.push( new THREE.Face3( 2, 3, 5 ) );
    geometry.faces.push( new THREE.Face3( 3,4, 5 ) );

    geometry.computeCentroids();
    geometry.computeFaceNormals();
    geometry.computeVertexNormals();

    init(geometry, true);
}

function init(geometry, isCustom) {

    camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera( 75, width/height, 1, 10000 );
    camera.position.z = 300;

    scene = new THREE.Scene();

    material = new THREE.MeshLambertMaterial( { color: 0xff0000  } );
    mesh = new THREE.Mesh( geometry, material );

    if (isCustom){
        material.side = THREE.DoubleSide;
        mesh.doubleSided = true;
    }

    scene.add( mesh );

    ambient = new THREE.AmbientLight( 0x101010 );
    ambient.position.set(0, -70, 100).normalize();
    scene.add( ambient );

    directionalLight = new THREE.DirectionalLight( 0xffffff );
    directionalLight.position = camera.position;
    scene.add( directionalLight );;

}

function animate() {

    // note: three.js includes requestAnimationFrame shim
    requestAnimationFrame( animate );

    render();
}
function render(){
    var delta = Date.now() - start;

    directionalLight.position = camera.position;

    //mesh.position.y = Math.abs( Math.sin( delta * 0.002 ) ) * 150;
    mesh.rotation.x = delta * 0.0003;
    mesh.rotation.z = delta * 0.0002;


    renderer.render( scene, camera );

}
```

I am pretty new to three.js and especially 3D rendering and any help is appreciated. Thanks in advance!

Comment: You may want to look at this issue listed on the main three.js site.  The relevant part is the discussion about the near and far value of the camera and the object you are viewing and how polygons gets "clipped" which is a nice way of saying the polygon will not be drawn it exists outside the near and far values of the camera.  It is a canvas renderer issue. https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/issues/1035#issuecomment-3423126

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your custom geometry, you need to specify the face vertices in counter-clockwise order.

With that fix, your custom geometry is fine.

Also, learn from current three.js examples. Your code is using outdated patterns. For example, `Vertex` has been deprecated. This new pattern is:

```
geometry.vertices.push( new THREE.Vector3( -100, 100, 0 ) );
```

http://jsfiddle.net/JLKCU/3/ - three.js r.54

Comment: Thanks for all of your help, your changes with the vertex order worked perfectly! Also thanks for the heads up on the lighting and shading issues as well.